Exoplasim mpiexec/scipy (?) error on Ubuntu WSL Windows 11
I have been trying to run exoplasim for a while now to no avail, going through Worldbuildingpasta's blog on how to install the program. I've gotten a multitude of errors even after repeated reinstalls of both WSL and exoplasim, but this latest one stumps me. The program below is what I'm running on the terminal.
import exoplasim as exo

teacup = exo.Model(workdir='teacup_run', modelname='teacup',
    outputtype='.nc', resolution='T42', layers=10,
    ncpus=8,precision=8, crashtolerant=False)

teacup.configure(timestep=40, runsteps=4896,
    otherargs={'NSTPW@plasim_namelist':'272'},
    flux=0.74*1367, startemp=4500,
    year=136, eccentricity=0.1, fixedorbit=True,
    rotationperiod=1+5/12, obliquity=30, lonvernaleq=80,
    gravity=8.47, radius=0.96,
    landmap='t64_surf_0172.sra', topomap='t64_surf_0129.sra',
    pN2=1.8, pO2=0.2, pCO2=0.0155,
    wetsoil=True, vegetation=2, initgrowth=0.5,
    glaciers={'toggle': True, 'mindepth': 2, 'initialh': -1})

teacup.cfgpostprocessor(times = 12)

teacup.exportcfg()

teacup.runtobalance(baseline=10, maxyears=100, minyears=10, timelimit=480,
          crashifbroken=True, clean=True)

teacup.finalize()

teacup.save()

The program runs as intended before this wall of text shows up.
3' of procedure 'mpputgp'
[ -e restart_dsnow ] && rm restart_dsnow
[ -e restart_xsnow ] && rm restart_xsnow
[ -e Abort_Message ] && exit 1
[ -e plasim_output ] && mv plasim_output MOST.00000
[ -e plasim_snapshot ] && mv plasim_snapshot MOST_SNAP.00000
[ -e plasim_diag ] && mv plasim_diag MOST_DIAG.00000
[ -e plasim_status ] && cp plasim_status plasim_restart
[ -e plasim_status ] && mv plasim_status MOST_REST.00000
[ -e restart_snow ] && mv restart_snow MOST_SNOW.00000
[ -e hurricane_indicators ] && mv hurricane_indicators MOST.00000.STORM
module 'scipy.integrate' has no attribute 'cumtrapz'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MOST.00000.'
Error writing output to MOST.00000..npz; log written to postprocess.log
Going to stop here just in case......
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpiexec command
      line parameter option (remember that mpiexec interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).

Node:       [user]legion
Executable: most_plasim_t42_l10_p8.x
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Immediately followed up by:
8 total processes failed to start
runtime crash
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user/teacup_crashed’: File exists
mv: cannot stat '/home/user/teacup_run/*': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/exoplasim/__init__.py", line 635, in runtobalance
    raise Exception("runtime crash")
Exception: runtime crash

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/teacup.py", line 22, in <module>
    teacup.runtobalance(baseline=10, maxyears=100, minyears=10, timelimit=480,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/exoplasim/__init__.py", line 749, in runtobalance
    self._crash() #Bring in the cleaners
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/exoplasim/__init__.py", line 1869, in _crash
    raise RuntimeError("ExoPlaSim has crashed or begun producing garbage. All working files have been moved to %s_crashed/"%(os.getcwd()+"/"+self.modelname))
RuntimeError: ExoPlaSim has crashed or begun producing garbage. All working files have been moved to /home/user/teacup_crashed/

If anyone could illuminate me as to what is going wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I see the line "module 'scipy.integrate' has no attribute 'cumtrapz'" It looks like this is not compatible with SciPy 1.14.0. Can you try downgrading? https://github.com/alphaparrot/ExoPlaSim/issues/31
